# wx.CallLater does not work for me

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to use wx.CallLater: I have two functions and they shall call each other in a loop, but with a break of 3 sec before every call. Problem is: When my program is in "goto01" it correctly waits 3 seconds before "Notify" is called. But when the program is in "Notify" then "goto01" is called immediatly. Why is there no break of 3 seconds at this point?
Here is my code & in the last line of each of the both functions I have a wx.CallLater event:

```
self.speed = 3000

def Notify(self):
    self.zeit.Destroy()
    self.zeitint = self.zeitint + 1
    time = round(self.zeitint/2)
    self.zeit = wx.StaticText(self.friendlygamepanel, -1, '%d. Spielminute'%(time), (325+self.dx,9))
    try:
        self.ticker.Destroy()
        self.picplayer1but.Destroy()

    except:
        pass
    if self.zeitint % 2 == 1:
        self.ticker = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, teamname[0]+' ist im Ballbesitz.',
                    size=(340, 320), pos=(195+self.dx,160), style=wx.TE_RICH2|wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_NO_VSCROLL)
        self.ticker.SetBackgroundColour((128,191,130))
        self.ticker.SetStyle(0, len(teamname[0]), wx.TextAttr("BLACK", wx.NullColour, self.font))
        wx.CallLater(int(self.speed),self.goto01(players,self.playerpics))

    else:
        self.ticker = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, oppteamname[0]+' ist im Ballbesitz.',
                    size=(340, 320), pos=(195+self.dx,160), style=wx.TE_RICH2|wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_NO_VSCROLL)
        self.ticker.SetBackgroundColour((205,173,65))
        self.ticker.SetStyle(0, len(oppteamname[0]), wx.TextAttr("BLACK", wx.NullColour, self.font))
        wx.CallLater(int(self.speed),self.goto01(oppplayers,self.oppplayerpics))


def goto01(self,theplayer,thepicture):
    if self.zeitint % 2 == 1:
        picpos = 0
    else:
        picpos = 460
    self.whichplayer = random.randint(0,2)
    self.whichoppplayer = random.randint(0,2)
    last = self.ticker.GetLastPosition()
    self.ticker.AppendText('\n\n'+theplayer[self.whichplayer][0]+' hat den Ball.')
    self.ticker.SetStyle(last, last+2+len(theplayer[self.whichplayer][0]), wx.TextAttr("BLACK", wx.NullColour, self.font))
    self.picplayer1 = wx.Image(thepicture[self.whichplayer], wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
    self.picplayer1but = wx.BitmapButton(self.friendlygamepanel,-1,self.picplayer1,pos=(90+self.dx+picpos,180))
    if self.zeitint < 60:
        wx.CallLater(int(self.speed),self.Notify)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the function with variables, you are telling wxPython to call it immediately. It's just like when you normally call a function. You can pass arguments to it though:

http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/wx-CallLater-issue-td4885884.html

As that link points out, the signature for CallLater is:

**(self, millis, callable, *args, **kwargs)**

Which means you should be able to do something like

```
wx.CallLater(numberOfMilliSecs, myFunction, arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: It's milliseconds, you wrote `numberOfSecs`

Comment: Too true. Sorry about that. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I see, when I just call "goto01" instead of "goto01(variable1,variable2)" then it works. I was able to change my code so that I don't have to use these variables when calling "goto", but I still don't know why wx.CallLater doesn't work with variables?!